# Acro package: using \aclp doesn't print defined long plural ending

Tags: acro

I defined a long plural ending differently than 's'. It only appears when the acronym is used first in plural form. If I use \aclp it is printed with 's' instead of the defined ending. Short plural endings which are defined other than 's' are printed with the defined ending.
In the past it worked, suddenly it doesn't work anymore. I updated acro, but still there is this problem. On a different computer with an older version it works.

```
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{Test}{
    short   =   Test ,
    long    =   TestTest ,
    short-plural    =   x ,
    long-plural =   y
}

\begin{document}

\acp{Test}  

\aclp{Test}

\acp{Test}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second line with \aclp isn't printed correctly, as it appears with 's' instead of the defined 'y' in this example. How can I get \aclp working properly?

Thanks for your answers!

Edit: I'm using acro v3.8 on texlive 2022 on a windows 10 home (v22H2) pc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which version of acro are you using?  This works fine for me with v3.8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm using  acro v3.8 on texlive 2022 on a windows 10 home (v22H2) pc.

Comment: @Natascha ok, sounds like something more than just a bug in acro, presumably you're running your example with `article` or another standard class?  Could you edit your question to add the log file from that minimal example?

Comment: @Natascha this shouldn't be happening, and isn't reproducible with the same version of `acro`, if the same document with a standard `\documentclass` is reproducing that error for you, the likely cause is some specific set of package versions. To diagnose any further we probably need the log file or `\listfiles` output to get a better idea of what's going on.